# Whitespace between <divs> on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a heat map from a .csv using jQuery and I am applying a range of values to `<div>` tags.

I am using `floats` to layout these `<div>` tags and nothing has an `inline-block` property applied to it.

When testing this heat map on a mobile device I notice there is whitespace between each element (see picture). This does not occur on desktop. On desktop it looks great.

[image: Heat map on mobile]

An example of my code is as follows:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
  <div class="column" data-value="1.4543434"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row::before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .column {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% / 24);
  }
  .column::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
  .column[data-value^="1"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="2"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="3"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="4"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="5"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="6"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="7"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="8"]::after,
  .column[data-value^="9"]::after {
    background: #ae2040;
  }
</style>
```

Does anyone know how to remove this whitespace and have the divs butt up against each other?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Using `Display: flex` instead of `float: left` doesn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all! https://jsfiddle.net/6L5vaoeo/

Comment: My mistake. I've fixed the errors. Shouldn't have hardcoded question ;)

Comment: It still doesn't display anything? https://jsfiddle.net/p45Laws1/

Comment: Oh I'm stupid, it hasn't got background color...

Comment: I've added class so background-color shows up.

Comment: Why don't you try to add border 1px?

Comment: I'm guessing it's maybe due to rounding? 100% / 24 is `4.166666...%`, which might cause this.

Comment: I tried to reduce size of my browser, still worked fine, but maybe mobile browser sees it in a different way, maybe float:left; is different for mobile browser

Comment: @ChrisG, I did wonder about that. But if that was the issue, `float:left;` would cause space on the right of the `.row` container. All the `.columns` would be hard up on the left.

Comment: @DjordjeVujicic, I should have mentioned that reducing the browser window on my laptop does't recreate the issue. Only in the context of Mobile Safari (and presumably other mobile browsers).

Comment: In any case, maybe adding border in a same color will fix it

Comment: @DjordjeVujicic adding border improves, but does not resolve issue. Cheers.

Comment: then try adding margines -1px for each element?